# Why is this jQuery dialog not working?

Tags: jquery

Dialog window is not launched when pressing the link, can you see anything wrong with my JS/HTML code?

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/LtQnT/

Comment: please post a short snippet of the code that is giving you a problem here, and describe 1. what it does, 2. what you expect it to do, and 3. what you have already tried to do to make it work. While you're at it update the question title as well - "not working" is not useful.

Comment: @Mat - Did you bother looking at the jsFiddle code? anyways, I've edited my question.

Comment: Seems as bug in jsfiddle. Even simple alert doesn't work...

Comment: no, I don't follow strange looking links, especially if I know in advance they contain code that doesn't work in an unspecified way...

Comment: @Mat - 'strange looking links', ok.., If you would have bothered looking, you would see that it contains very little code and it's very obvious what it should do. You are right, I should have edited the description of my question in a better way, but you can bother looking into things before you write your comments.

Comment: the point of this site is to have questions and their answers, easily searchable and easily referenced. I have no idea how long this URL you provided will survive. it's not a good way to present the information in your question. if you want people to help you, help them first and make your problem as clear as possible at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<a href="javascript:forgotPassword();">` and `forgotPassword` function is defined inside `$(document).ready`. To make it work you need either to move definition of `forgotPassword` outside of `ready` or do something like

```
<a id='my_link' href='javascript:void(0)'>Forgot</a>
$(document).ready(function() {
 .... 
  $("#my_link").click(function(e){ 
$("#forgot-dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: `href='javascript:void(0)'`? people should really start stop using crap like that. `e.preventDefault();` is the way to go (and either use `href="#"` or point it to a page for those who have JavaScript disabled)

Answer (score 5):

I tweaked your code a little bit, so it works now:

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#forgot').click(function() {
        $( "#forgot-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#forgot-dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 255,
            width: 300,
            buttons: {
                "Retrieve": function() {
                    document.forms["forgotform"].submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="forgot">Forgot?</a>

<div id="forgot-dialog" style="display:none;" title="Reset your password">
<form id="forgotform" action="/forgotPassword.php" method="post">
<label for="forgot_email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="forgot_email" id="forgot_email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="<?= $fb_email ?>" />
</form>
</div>
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HxbTY/.

You weren't including jQuery UI, as `dialog()` is part of jQuery UI, not jQuery.

I'm not sure why that function didn't fire (probably a jsFiddle.net bug), but I added a `click()` handler to the link to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few problems with your fiddle.

First, you didn't include the jquery UI as a library so obviously your code will fail. You also need to include the CSS. There were some scope issues as well, I've fixed those and posted the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/LtQnT/11/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theLink').click(function(){
                $( "#forgot-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );    
    });

    $( "#forgot-dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 255,
            width: 300,
            buttons: {
                "Retrieve": function() {
                    document.forms["forgotform"].submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
    });
});
```

Comment: Ha, we posted completely identical solutions.

Comment: ha ha yeah true,  I suppose there's only one correct answer! +1 to you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/LtQnT/9/

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `forgotPassword()` function in an anonymous scope which is a good thing. However, inline Javascript - which is a bad thing anyway - cannot access it anymore.

Use this code instead: `<a href="#" id="forgotPasswordLink">Forgot?</a>`

In your on ready code: `$('#forgotPasswordLink').click(forgotPassword);` - merge those two separate `$(document).ready()` functions in a single one though: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/LtQnT/13/

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
   $('#theLink').click(function(){
                   $( "#dialog" ).dialog();    
    });

  } );
  </script>
  
 <a id='theLink' href="#">Forgot?</a> 
  
  <div id="dialog" title="Forgot Password" style="display:none;">
  <div id="forgot-dialog"  title="Reset your password">
<form id="forgotform" action="/forgotPassword.php" method="post">
<label for="forgot_email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="forgot_email" id="forgot_email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="<?= $fb_email ?>" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```